# How can I rewrite this dynamic SQL loop to include PDO sanitization?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this awesome loop from a question I asked yesterday. Previously, I could use mysql_real_escape_string($val) and that would handle protection against injection attacks and such. With PDO, however, there is not quite as simple of a function.

What can I do?

```
if (($_GET['mode'] == "update") and isset($_GET['id']) and isset($_POST['who'])) {

    $query = "update subcontractors set";
    $comma = " ";

    $whitelist = array("firstname","lastname","address","city","state","zip","phone1","phone2","phone3","email","dob","ssn","website","checks");

    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if ( !empty($val) && in_array($key, $whitelist)) {
            $query .= $comma . $key . "='" . $val . "'";
            $comma = ", ";
        }
    }
    $query .= " where id=" . $_POST['who'];

    include "connect.php";
    $db->query($query); 
} #endif UPDATE SECTION
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using prepared statements? That should protect quite well against SQL injection. Although, you can look into [Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) to filter your input.

Comment: Using prepared statements wouldn't allow me to generate the statement dynamically based on a whitelist though, would it? I would have to manually write out each line for each variable, which could be quite extensive for a larger form.

Comment: With whitelist you are trying to check if for example $_POST['firstname'] is posted?

Comment: Yes, basically. Using a whitelist also allows me to pass other parameters via POST that I maybe do not want to include in my foreach loop. I could pass 100 parameter, just act on the 10 I have in my whitelist, and use the other 90 in another loop that acts on a different database/table.

Comment: I wouldn't go for a loop approach on that. I would basically create a stored procedure for each case and call that on my php code. I understand that you want minimal code since there are a lot of parameters as you explain. But i don't see in any example using backticks. Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a MySQL reserved keyword. And since i have not seen all 100 parameters as you say i can't know if one of those parameters is in fact a MySQL reserved keyword.

Comment: @PeterDarmis So I should be fine with this approach if none of my parameters are MySQL reserved keywords, right? Minimal code is what I was shooting for here, yes. 100 was an exaggeration, but you get the idea. The two other sections I will use this in are probably closer to double and triple the amount of parameters shown here.

Comment: yes. i made an edit to the above answer should be visible in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the code in several small ways:

- In the loop, it is now building a prepared statement instead of a full query. I replaced the $val variable that was being inserted into the sql statement with a "?" placeholder.

  $query .= $comma . $key . "= ?";
- In the loop, I place the $val into an array that will later be used to bind to the placeholders when the statement is executed.

  $params[] = $val;
- I call the prepare method of the PDO object and pass it the $query variable as an argument:

  $sth = $db->prepare($query);
- I call the execute method on the $sth (which is an object of the PDOStatement class) and pass it the $param array as an arguement. It will bind the array values to the placeholders in order:

  $sth->execute($params);

This will protect you from injection.

```
 if (($_GET['mode'] == "update") and isset($_GET['id']) and isset($_POST['who'])) {

        $query = "update subcontractors set";
        $comma = " ";
        $params = array();

        $whitelist = array("firstname","lastname","address","city","state","zip","phone1","phone2","phone3","email","dob","ssn","website","checks");

        foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
            if ( !empty($val) && in_array($key, $whitelist)) {
                $query .= $comma . $key . "= ?";
                $params[] = $val;
                $comma = ", ";
            }
        }
        $query .= " where id=?";
        $params[] = $_POST['who'];
        include "connect.php";
        $sth = $db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute($params); 
    } #endif UPDATE SECTION
```

For more info on prepared statements with PDO please read the following:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I don't quite grasp what's happening here. I still obviously have the whitelist, though. It looks like you created a new array, and add the keys into the new array as you go. You are left with a single update statement that has x number of wild cards in it and an array with matching x number of values? at that point, the sth->execute($params) bit executes the command with the array values inserted?

Comment: I got it, this is perfect. Is it not supposed to be $params[] = $val though? I don't want to insert the keys, i want to insert the values, of course.

Comment: And I changed the $params[] = $key to $params[] = $val (I was moving to fast :) ) . I edited the answer to explain what is happening.

Comment: Brilliant! I have learned from this, thank you very much! You just need to edit $key to $val in your explanation portion in the top now, haha :)

Comment: What is $sth short for?\

Comment: Edit complete. $sth is a common idiom; it is short for statement handle.

Comment: It is truncating input after single quotation marks? Is that expected? In a notes field, how would someone include a contraction?

Comment: Is it truncated in the database or when you pull it out and print it back to screen. I seriously doubt that it is the former, the later can be solved with  the htmlentities() function

Comment: Good call. Replying from mobile so I can't test, but I bet you are correct.

Comment: You've pointed me in the right direction, but how should I go about solving this. Do I have to put a convert on the variable pre-database and then unconvert it when I display it, or just on display? What's the standard practice here?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are too many parameters and too many forms and databases then it might be best to create some stored procedures and call each one depending the case/form being submitted. As for the above example i would go for a not dynamic solution in this case. Only because a field in your whitelist array could be a MySQL reserved keyword something that it would cause an error when the MySQL server executes your query.

```
  if (($_GET['mode'] == "update") and isset($_GET['id']) and isset($_POST['who'])) {
    include "connect.php";
    $stmt = dbh->prepare("UPDATE `subcontractors` SET `firstname`=:firstname,`lastname`=:lastname,`address`=:address,`city`=:city,`state`=:state,`zip`=:zip,`phone1`=:phone1,`phone2`=:phone2,`phone3`=:phone3,`email`=:email,`dob`=:dob,`ssn`=:ssn,`website`=:website,`checks`=:checks WHERE `id`=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':state', $_POST['state']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':zip', $_POST['zip']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone1', $_POST['phone1']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone2', $_POST['phone2']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone3', $_POST['phone3']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':dob', $_POST['dob']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ssn', $_POST['ssn']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':website', $_POST['website']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':checks', $_POST['checks']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['who']);
    $stmt->execute();
    } #endif UPDATE SECTION
```

Comment: This could get quite lengthy and problems can be avoided entirely so long as none of my parameters are keywords, right?

Comment: The keywords are these http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html but it writes reserved words in MySQL 5.5 which means that everything changes and words are added or deleted anytime. it is much more preferable to not to have to look at this list every time. Using backticks in your array e.g. `firstname`,`lastname` will not work with the above code in your example. The solution you have from @dlporter98 is great, but to me if you do have the time to use stored procedures then i strongly recommend it.

Comment: I definitely see your point now, as I did not previously consider that the list could change. Could we not merge the two examples and generate this list with backticks in a loop?

Comment: i have to write it as word since it gets highlighted as code in the comment box $query .= $comma . "backtick".$key . "backtick= ?";

Comment: modifying that line to what you wrote would solve the issues you presented, right? that's all that would be needed? exchanging backtick with ` of course

Comment: Yes. But as i wrote above since you have to work with many parameters / fields / forms and databases on your script, try to set it up differently by using stored procedures, prepared statements and your own php classes depending the case you have each time in your hands. I do totally of course understand the way you want your code to be minimal which is correct for me since i do try to work this way. If by one routine you can do 2 things and have it done correctly with absolutely no error then this is best approach to my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`$query .= $comma . $key . "=" . $db->quote($val);` this escapes the string and the single quotes are added automatically

Comment: Does this prevent injection attacks? This seems too simple, haha.

Comment: it's the same as mysqli_real_escape_string() other than this one also adds the single quotes for you.

Comment: It appears that this does not prevent injection attacks, which is the main reason I am asking. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: i would recommend learning prepared statements though since they are usually safer and perform better.